# Animation of scanning, transition to the other layer on effect

Tags: layers, animation, effects, adobe-after-effects, terminology

I want to create a transition using scanning effect (horizontal line going from a head to a toes of a character). Basically let's say I have two layers, one with green human, and second wth red human. Horizontal line while moving from up to bottom, switches layers, showing partially green/red human, then ending on showing only red one.

What should I do, in order to create an effect where this line, while going down, switching layer with the character to other layer.
Also, is there any name for this kind of effect? Is it parallax?

Comment: In the "old days" of television, images were transmitted by individual lines, called scan lines. It used a process known as interlacing, which is still seen today. A 1080p is progressive, a 1080i (rare) is interlaced. It sounds like you want an interlacing effect.

Comment: I meant that effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_iglhY9jk3g

Comment: It appears that you've found the desired effect as well as a tutorial for creating it. Am I incorrect in my understanding?

Comment: Yes, I didn't find exact one that I desire to create. This is only similar concept, and I am looking for something like this

Answer (score 1):

## Wipe Motion Transition

About the name, this is something that I learned here in one of my questions:

[Graphic term for precise/geometric double exposure images](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/119817/120647)

And this is the link from [monzoom.com](http://monzoom.com) with the the examples

[image]