# Graphic term for precise/geometric double exposure images

Tags: terminology

I need to find a graphic term that allows me to do a search of mixed split images with a clear division, no matter the type, especially photos. I don't find anything that fits, I tried with *split images*, *double exposure*, *double images*, *divided images* (which shows me a picture of Donald Trump...)

**[Double exposure](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5MACD_enFR506FR507&biw=1673&bih=1200&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=Ag9TXMiVCIqIjLsPy_mn2As&q=double%20exposure&oq=double%20exposure&gs_l=img.3..0l10.5418.123999..124517...0.0..0.114.1316.15j1......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i19j0i7i30i19j35i39j0i67.5l8N2bUYRXY)** is the closest but the type of blend is a fade, I can't find the adjective for a geometric or precise cut.

A simple sketch of the image type I'm looking for.

[image]

I just need the term to make a specific search and look for more examples like the one below, it's like a video transition frozen frame:

[image]

In other words, if I use this:

[image: operation]

to make this:

[image: Result]

what's the name of the resulting image?

---

In [zeustudio.com](https://zeustudio.com/master-hot-design-trends-with-these-photoshop-tutorials-2) they call it **Photo Masking Cutouts**, but Google Search doesn't show much results.

[image: Photo Masking Cutouts]

---

[George Chamoun](https://trendland.com/iconatomy-by-george-chamoun/) use a custom name for a specific project: **Iconatomy**, but it's the same idea

[image: iconatomy]

---

Add after the answer:

In relation to the valid answer I found animated **Wipe Gradient Transition** examples in [monzoon.com](https://www.monzoom.com/category/wipe-motion-transitions.html)

Comment: Anything, images in general, I just need the term to do a search. I will add another example.

Comment: Question updated...

Comment: A specific subset of these images are [comparison image sliders](https://www.google.com/search?q=comparison+image+slider&num=20&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK_JXNqpjgAhWJhVQKHZRbCOMQ_AUIDigB&biw=1536&bih=722)

Comment: Yes, it's pretty close, except for the slider. I'll try it anyway.

Comment: [Split portrait pictures](https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&biw=1536&bih=722&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=wCdTXJTqNo2itQX20puwCA&q=split+portrait+pictures&oq=split+portrait+pictures&gs_l=img.3...739.3611..4181...5.0..0.309.1392.6j2j1j1......0....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i8i7i30.S_u79ydv_xg) returns results similar to your first set of images

Comment: I think as your search has found, there is no unanimous name for this sort of thing.

Comment: I found several examples in [pinterest.es](https://www.pinterest.es/pin/345580971385086750/) but it has no any associated name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the term ‘Linear Wipe’

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is a double exposure concept... it is just a

"Before and After"

But of course, the initial concept might be used as anything you want...

It also can just be one of the simpler examples of a collage.

Answer (score 1):

1. Split Screen
2. Before After
3. Photo Stitching
4. Image Splicing

Works for me when searching for images in all the major stock photo websites.

Answer (score 1):

The practice of combining separate images into an unexpected new composition is sometimes referred to as **Exquisite Corpse** or **Picture Consequences** (i).

Exquisite Corpse was originally a Surrealist word-game where a player would write down words, hand it to another collaborator who would then complete the sentence.

A collage technique derived from this uses imagery instead of words. Sections of photographed subjects or drawings are combined together into one unique result (ii).

Here are some examples (iii):
[image]

---

i. Brotchie, A. and Gooding, M. (1995). A book of surrealist games. Boston: Shambhala Redstone Editions.

ii. Ambrose, G. and Harris, P. (2011). Layout. Lausanne, Switzerland: AVA Pub.

iii. Honolulu Museum of Art (2015). Exquisite Corpse [Accessed 28 May 2019].

Answer (score 0):

The final product as a noun (not the process as a verb) may be called:

1. Photo Montage
2. Collage
3. Transformation
4. Composition

Comment: Why not include this in your original answer?

Comment: b/c @Danielillo edited his original question. He clarified that he is looking for a noun and not a verb. Additionally, if he already read the initial post, edits may go unnoticed as readers scan the page for new answers. He may not recognize that I added some bullets.